# Change date format on Select cast average

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

How to change the date format? I have this query and want to add `` DATE_FORMAT(`tanggal`,'%M') `` to it.

```
SELECT
    CAST(
      AVG(
        0.7*nilai_output + 
        0.1*nilai_atasan + 
        0.05*nilai_learning + 
        0.05*nilai_kedisiplinan
      ) AS DECIMAL (10,2)
    ) AS average, 
    tkaryawans.*
FROM tkaryawans 
ORDER BY tanggal DESC
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the requirement to include a date (or month of a date) in the select clause implies that you want to really aggregate by this date quantity.  I suggest aggregating by year and month, to cover the possibility that your data might have more than one year in it:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%Y-%m') AS date,
    CAST(AVG(0.7*nilai_output + 0.1*nilai_atasan + 0.05*nilai_learning +
             0.05*nilai_kedisiplinan) AS DECIMAL (10,2)) AS average
FROM tkaryawans
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(tanggal, '%Y-%m')
ORDER BY
    date DESC;
```